# folders of apps not downloaded created in my memory card

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I use Sony Xperia Z phone
Recently i noticed that in my phone some empty folders of applications like hike and hookup are created. I did not download these applications...so how these folders came in my memory card. I had recently mounted my memory card in my friends phone which had these apps.. is it possible that these folders got copied from his phone to my memory card ? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes exactly. Applications create (not copy) required folders as soon as a memory card is mounted. There is nothing to worry about and you can delete them manually. As an extra note - these folders are created for saving media files received and backup files.

Comment: Thank u Mr. Mani for ur reply. But i have one more querry. To check the above, I put a new memory card in my samsung galaxy note phone which has hike as well as hookup apps. Here in this memory card no such folders were created. So is it that these empty folders are created in some phones and not in others because i tried this on 3 memory cards and none of them got such empty folders created. Pls help.

Comment: Latest google restrictions doesn't allow accessing memory card for saving data or installing by almost all the apps. Maybe the previous phone allows that.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand this. Could u explain in simple language please.

Comment: Latest versions of android doesn't support apps to be installed on memory card and also doesn't support moving applications to SD card. Previous versions support these things.